# Swift 4: Redundant conformance of 'ViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, swift

currently creating a practice project, i don't really like storyboards, i want to stick with code..

today, i created a `SearchViewController` using this code

```
 @IBAction func showSearch(_ sender: Any) {

    var resultvc = UITableViewController(style: .plain)
    let searchvc = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultvc)
    self.present(searchvc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

okay so this is fine when i click the button everything works as expected, but when trying to put something in the `searchResultsController`

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text =  "\(indexPath.row) - Its working"
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
}

// MARK: - Table View Delegate
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!
        print(currentCell.textLabel!.text!)

    }
}
```

i get :

> Redundant conformance of 'ViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

is there any different ways to put something in the resultTableView without storyboard's

Comment: Please show the definition of your `class ViewController` - does is subclass `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController`?

Comment: what is self.resultvc ? when you're creating a local variable of resultvc.

Comment: @ArunKumar, it's global, i just written it for reference of this post

Comment: @AndreasOetjen, it's  UIViewController

Comment: How did you set resultvc.tableview.datasource & delegate?

Comment: @ArunKumar, `resultvc.tableView.delegate = self`

Comment: where did you set them? As I can't see them in your code?

Comment: @ArunKumar, just in the showSearch mate, the question has to be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a cell for identifier "reuseIdentifier" . Use these lines of code

```
self.resultvc = UITableViewController(style: .plain)
self.resultvc.tableView.dataSource = self
self.resultvc.tableView.delegate = self
self.resultvc.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
let searchvc = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultvc)
self.present(searchvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: appreciate the answer, please use the complete code to make a complete answer so i can give the green checkmark, thanks.

Comment: what does this solution have to do with the "redundant conformance" error message?

Comment: Well... exactly I don't know because there is not mentioned that 'ViewController' is subclass of UITableViewController or UIViewController. But this error comes only when you make your ViewController subclass of UITableViewController and conform with UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate. 
And about the solution , it is just about how to initialize UITableViewController programmatically which I have found as an issue in the code.